# Unwrap String and check emptiness in the same if statement

Tags: swift

I want to achieve this

```
if let large = imageLinks.large {

    if !large.isEmpty {

        result = large
    }
}
```

in a single if statement, something like this (this does not compiles)

```
if let large = imageLinks.large where !large.isEmpty {

    result = large       
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Your code should work in my opinion. What's the error you got?

Comment: @Christian I've updated to Swift 1.2 and now it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check string for nil & empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381994/check-string-for-nil-empty)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It 's not yet possible.
With the actual Version of swift the if let statement is pretty poor.

But with **Swift 1.2** (it will be available in Xcode 6.3).
You will be able to do this:

(SWIFT 1.2)

```
if let large = imageLinks.large where !large.isEmpty {

    result = large       
}
```

But now you cannot.
You can do something like:

```
if  imageLinks.large != nil && !imageLinks.large!.isEmpty {
   result = large!;
}
```

Note:
Swift use "Lazy Evaluation"
If the first part `imageLinks.large != nil` is false it will not Evaluate the second part, so it will not crash.

But I don't found this solution beautiful (too much force unwrapping).

Answer (score 6):

In swift 4.4, generics to the rescue \o/

```
public extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var isEmptyOrNil: Bool { (self ?? "").isEmpty }
}
```

usage

```
if nameField.text.isEmptyOrNil {
    //doSomething...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 1.1

If you don't like force unwrapping, you can:

```
if let large = imageLinks.large?.isEmpty == false ? imageLinks.large : nil {
    result = large
}
```

It's not so beautiful anyway :(