# Check string for nil & empty

Tags: swift, string, option-type, is-empty

Is there a way to check strings for `nil` and `""` in Swift? In Rails, I can use `blank()` to check.

I currently have this, but it seems overkill:

```
    if stringA? != nil {
        if !stringA!.isEmpty {
            ...blah blah
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unwrap String and check emptiness in the same if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164670/unwrap-string-and-check-emptiness-in-the-same-if-statement)

Comment: (@sutra and @imanou-petit)'s answers are better.

Answer (score 253):

If you're dealing with optional Strings, this works:

```
(string ?? "").isEmpty
```

The `??` nil coalescing operator returns the left side if it's non-nil, otherwise it returns the right side.

You can also use it like this to return a default value:

```
(string ?? "").isEmpty ? "Default" : string!
```

Comment: what is the benefit of using isEmpty over  == "" comparison? Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 85):

You could perhaps use the if-let-where clause:

Swift 3:

```
if let string = string, !string.isEmpty {
    /* string is not blank */
}
```

Swift 2:

```
if let string = string where !string.isEmpty {
    /* string is not blank */
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with Swift 2, getting this run time error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` but my constant `string` has a string data.

Comment: This works in Swift 3:
`if let string = string, !string.isEmpty {
  /* string is not blank */
}`

Comment: @AmrLotfy `guard let` is an alternative if you want to end control flow below the statement. However nothing is being unwrapped in the where clause here (the ! is a boolean negation)

Comment: so how about this
 !str?.isEmpty instead of string = string where !string.isEmpty

Answer (score 43):

With Swift 5, you can implement an `Optional` extension for `String` type with a boolean property that returns if an optional string is empty or has no value:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {

    var isEmptyOrNil: Bool {
        return self?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

}
```

However, `String` implements `isEmpty` property by conforming to protocol `Collection`. Therefore we can replace the previous code's generic constraint (`Wrapped == String`) with a broader one (`Wrapped: Collection`) so that `Array`, `Dictionary` and `Set` also benefit our new `isEmptyOrNil` property:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Collection {

    var isEmptyOrNil: Bool {
        return self?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

}
```

---

Usage with `String`s:

```
let optionalString: String? = nil
print(optionalString.isEmptyOrNil) // prints: true
```

```
let optionalString: String? = ""
print(optionalString.isEmptyOrNil) // prints: true
```

```
let optionalString: String? = "Hello"
print(optionalString.isEmptyOrNil) // prints: false
```

Usage with `Array`s:

```
let optionalArray: Array<Int>? = nil
print(optionalArray.isEmptyOrNil) // prints: true
```

```
let optionalArray: Array<Int>? = []
print(optionalArray.isEmptyOrNil) // prints: true
```

```
let optionalArray: Array<Int>? = [10, 22, 3]
print(optionalArray.isEmptyOrNil) // prints: false
```

---

Sources:

- [swiftbysundell.com - Extending optionals in Swift](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/extending-optionals-in-swift)
- [objc.io - Swift Tip: Non-Empty Collections](https://www.objc.io/blog/2019/01/29/non-empty-collections/)

Comment: I like this, the only tweak I would make is to rename it from `isNilOrEmpty` to `isEmptyOrNil` to match the prefix so it's easily findable via the same pattern for autocomplete. I've noticed more adoption of this extension from colleagues I work with just from them finding it this way.

Answer (score 34):

## Using the [`guard`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/guard-statement) statement

I was using Swift for a while before I learned about the [`guard`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/guard-statement) statement. Now I am a big fan. It is used similarly to the [`if`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/if-statement) statement, but it allows for [early return](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-guard) and just makes for much cleaner code in general.

To use guard when checking to make sure that a string is neither nil nor empty, you can do the following:

```
let myOptionalString: String? = nil

guard let myString = myOptionalString, !myString.isEmpty else {
    print("String is nil or empty.")
    return // or break, continue, throw
}

/// myString is neither nil nor empty (if this point is reached)
print(myString)
```

This unwraps the optional string and checks that it isn't empty all at once. If it is nil (or empty), then you return from your function (or loop) immediately and everything after it is ignored. But if the guard statement passes, then you can safely use your unwrapped string.

## See Also

- [Statements documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID428)
- [The Guard Statement in Swift 2](http://www.codingexplorer.com/the-guard-statement-in-swift-2/)

Comment: be careful. print(myString) will not run, if String is nil or empty,   because guard is designed not to fall down after come into else phase.

Comment: @KangByul, that's correct and is the intent of the logic here. Presumably if the string is `nil` or empty, one would not want to call `print(myString)`. If you needed to continue execution after a `nil` or empty `String`, then you would use `if let` rather than `guard`.

Comment: Thanks for a commend. I know, I just tell other ones who dont know about guard much.

Comment: @KangByul I do not understand the point of your "be careful" comment, I think it scares people off from a great solution, the return statement is clearly right in the guard else statement, I think you should delete your comment

Answer (score 30):

If you are using Swift 2, here is an example my colleague came up with, which adds isNilOrEmpty property on optional Strings:

```
protocol OptionalString {}
extension String: OptionalString {}

extension Optional where Wrapped: OptionalString {
    var isNilOrEmpty: Bool {
        return ((self as? String) ?? "").isEmpty
    }
}
```

You can then use isNilOrEmpty on the optional string itself

```
func testNilOrEmpty() {
    let nilString:String? = nil
    XCTAssertTrue(nilString.isNilOrEmpty)

    let emptyString:String? = ""
    XCTAssertTrue(emptyString.isNilOrEmpty)

    let someText:String? = "lorem"
    XCTAssertFalse(someText.isNilOrEmpty)
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you did here or some resource which can explain this in detail. Like why OptionalString is declared? I am not getting the Syntax. It is not like normal extension implementation So. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @VinayakParmar OptionalString is declared here because the `where Wrapped:` must specify a protocol and not a type.

Comment: Maybe you could name `isNilOrEmpty` to `hasValue` (or something like that) and reverse the logic

Answer (score 15):

```
var str: String? = nil

if str?.isEmpty ?? true {
    print("str is nil or empty")
}

str = ""

if str?.isEmpty ?? true {
    print("str is nil or empty")
}
```

Comment: Elegant but awkward ;), the "true" kinda throws off the intution

Answer (score 12):

I know there are a lot of answers to this question, but none of them seems to be as convenient as this (in my opinion) to validate `UITextField` data, which is one of the most common cases for using it:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var isNilOrEmpty: Bool {
        return self?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty ?? true
    }
}
```

You can just use

```
textField.text.isNilOrEmpty
```

You can also skip the `.trimmingCharacters(in:.whitespaces)` if you don't consider whitespaces as an empty string or use it for more complex input tests like

```
var isValidInput: Bool {
    return !isNilOrEmpty && self!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).characters.count >= MIN_CHARS
}
```

Comment: Great answer, the Op didn't precise if whitespaces where counted as blank so here is my version : 
public extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var isEmptyOrNil: Bool { return (self ?? "").isEmpty }
}

Answer (score 10):

If you want to access the string as a non-optional, you should use [Ryan's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31867504/195691), but if you only care about the non-emptiness of the string, my preferred shorthand for this is

```
if stringA?.isEmpty == false {
    ...blah blah
}
```

Since `==` works fine with optional booleans, I think this leaves the code readable without obscuring the original intention.

If you want to check the opposite: if the string is `nil` or `""`, I prefer to check both cases explicitly to show the correct intention:

```
if stringA == nil || stringA?.isEmpty == true {
    ...blah blah
}
```

Comment: @TruMan1 that's correct, the goal of the first example is to check if the string is _not_ empty.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend.

```
if stringA.map(isEmpty) == false {
    println("blah blah")
}
```

`map` applies the function argument if the optional is `.Some`.
The playground capture also shows another possibility with the new Swift 1.2 if let optional binding.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT 3**

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {

    /// Checks to see whether the optional string is nil or empty ("")
    public var isNilOrEmpty: Bool {
        if let text = self, !text.isEmpty { return false }
        return true
    }
}
```

Use like this on optional string:

```
if myString.isNilOrEmpty { print("Crap, how'd this happen?") }
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3
For check Empty String best way

```
if !string.isEmpty{

// do stuff

}
```

Comment: This won't even compile since `string` is optional.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 solution
Use the optional unwrapped value and check against the boolean.

```
if (string?.isempty == true) {
    // Perform action
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this:
`if !(string?.isEmpty ?? true) { //Not nil nor empty }`

Nil coalescing operator checks if the optional is not nil, in case it is not nil it then checks its property, in this case isEmpty. Because this optional can be nil you provide a default value which will be used when your optional is nil.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@joshua.a.kahn/swift-quick-tip-check-if-string-is-not-nil-and-not-empty-1f57a30f3769), with a little tweak for Swift 5, I got to this code that worked.

```
if let stringA, !stringA.isEmpty {
    ...blah blah
}
```

Although I understand the benefits of creating an extension, I thought it might help someone needing just for a small component / package.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom function, if that is something you expect to do a lot.

```
func isBlank (optionalString :String?) -> Bool {
    if let string = optionalString {
        return string.isEmpty
    } else {
        return true
    }
}



var optionalString :String? = nil

if isBlank(optionalString) {
    println("here")
}
else {
    println("there")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a String class extension:

```
extension String
{   //  returns false if passed string is nil or empty
    static func isNilOrEmpty(_ string:String?) -> Bool
    {   if  string == nil                   { return true }
        return string!.isEmpty
    }
}// extension: String
```

Notice this will return TRUE if the string contains one or more blanks. To treat blank string as "empty", use...

```
return string!.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces).isEmpty
```

... instead. This requires Foundation.

Use it thus...

```
if String.isNilOrEmpty("hello world") == true 
{   print("it's a string!")
}
```

Comment: Using a force unwrap in code that is supposed to see if something is nil or empty is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3
This works well to check if the string is really empty. Because isEmpty returns true when there's a whitespace.

```
extension String {
    func isEmptyAndContainsNoWhitespace() -> Bool {
        guard self.isEmpty, self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty
            else {
               return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
let myString = "My String"
myString.isEmptyAndContainsNoWhitespace() // returns false

let myString = ""
myString.isEmptyAndContainsNoWhitespace() // returns true

let myString = " "
myString.isEmptyAndContainsNoWhitespace() // returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using isEmpty**

```
"Hello".isEmpty  // false
"".isEmpty       // true
```

**Using allSatisfy**

```
extension String {
  var isBlank: Bool {
    return allSatisfy({ $0.isWhitespace })
  }
}

"Hello".isBlank        // false
"".isBlank             // true
```

**Using optional String**

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
  var isBlank: Bool {
    return self?.isBlank ?? true
  }
}

var title: String? = nil
title.isBlank            // true
title = ""               
title.isBlank            // true
```

Reference : https://useyourloaf.com/blog/empty-strings-in-swift/

Answer (score 1):

This is a general solution for all types that conform to the `Collection` protocol, which includes `String`:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Collection {
    var isNilOrEmpty: Bool {
        self?.isEmpty ?? true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.6 - Xcode 13**

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Collection {
  var isEmptyOrNil: Bool {
    guard let self = self else { return true }
    return self.isEmpty
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var name: String?

if name.isEmptyOrNil { 
  ///true
}

name = "John Peter"

guard !name.isEmptyOrNil else { return } 
/// Name is not empty
```

Comment: You can also simply do `self?.isEmpty ?? true;`

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with passing values from local db to server and vice versa, I was having too much trouble with ?'s and !'s and what not.

So I made a Swift3.0 utility to handle null cases and i can almost totally avoid ?'s and !'s in the code.

```
func str(_ string: String?) -> String {
    return (string != nil ? string! : "")
}
```

Ex:-

Before :

```
    let myDictionary: [String: String] = 
                      ["title": (dbObject?.title != nil ? dbObject?.title! : "")]
```

After :

```
    let myDictionary: [String: String] = 
                        ["title": str(dbObject.title)]
```

and when its required to check for a valid string,

```
    if !str(dbObject.title).isEmpty {
        //do stuff
    }
```

This saved me having to go through the trouble of adding and removing numerous ?'s and !'s after writing code that reasonably make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ternary operator (also known as the conditional operator, `C++ forever!`):

`if stringA != nil ? stringA!.isEmpty == false : false { /* ... */ }`

The `stringA!` force-unwrapping happens only when `stringA != nil`, so it is safe. The `== false` verbosity is somewhat more readable than yet another exclamation mark in `!(stringA!.isEmpty)`.

I personally prefer a slightly different form:

`if stringA == nil ? false : stringA!.isEmpty == false { /* ... */ }`

In the statement above, it is immediately very clear that the entire `if` block does not execute when a variable is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

helpful when getting value from **UITextField**  and checking for `nil` & `empty` string

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
```

Heres your function (when you tap on a `button`) that gets string from UITextField and does some other stuff

```
@IBAction func getStringFrom_myTextField(_ sender: Any) {

guard let string = myTextField.text, !(myTextField.text?.isEmpty)!  else { return }
    //use "string" to do your stuff.
}
```

This will take care of `nil` value as well as `empty` string.

It worked perfectly well for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String? {
    var isEmptyOrNil: Bool {
        guard let self else { return true }
        return self.isEmpty
    }
}
```

usage

```
var string1: String?
var string2: String? = "test3"
var string3: String? = ""

print(string1.isEmptyOrNil) // true
print(string2.isEmptyOrNil) // false
print(string3.isEmptyOrNil) // true
```

Comment: this answer would be useful if you explain where to put the extension

Answer (score -4):

you can use this func

```
 class func stringIsNilOrEmpty(aString: String) -> Bool { return (aString).isEmpty }
```

Comment: Not a swift user; could you explain why this doesn't throw an exception if nil is passed?

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception because you cannot pass `nil` into this function at all (except from objc, in which case it will indeed crash).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It doesn't check for nil as it doesn't accept an optional