# getting "Use of unresolved identifier 'self'" when trying to present AlertViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to write a function that displays a `UIAlertController` when a `UITextField` is left empty.  I used the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905329/shows-the-alert-when-uitextfields-are-full-or-empty-swift) to display the message.  At this stage, I get the following error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

The code I have is below.

```
func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: String){
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `self` refers to in this case? Is this function definition inside a class that extends `ViewController`?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to extend the viewcontroller .

Comment: Where exactly is this `displayMyAlertMessage` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that your `func` is not inside any UIViewController subclass declaration. Thus there is no `self` (or `self` is not a view controller, so there is no `self.present`).