# If UITextField is blank UIAlert does not appear

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller, uipickerviewcontroller

I have an application with 4 UITextFields and what I want to do is display a UIAlert if a UITextfield is blank.  I have the function I have chosen to display the UIAlert which [image]is as follows:

```
func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: String) {
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have looked at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905329/shows-the-alert-when-uitextfields-are-full-or-empty-swift) and could not get it to work as I have UIPickerView to display the text.  Below is the code I for didSelectRow :

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if TrackTextField.isFirstResponder {
        selectedTrack = tracks[row]
        guard let track = selectedTrack?.isEmpty else {
            displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "You have to fill in a track")
            return
        }
        TrackTextField.text = String(track)
    } else if firstTextField.isFirstResponder {
        firstDriver = drivers[row]
        firstTextField.text = firstDriver
    } else if secondTextField.isFirstResponder {
        secondDriver = drivers[row]
        secondTextField.text = secondDriver
    } else if thirdTextField.isFirstResponder {
        thirdDriver = drivers[row]
        thirdTextField.text = thirdDriver
    }
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "getPredictor" {
        let predictorVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let vc = predictorVC.topViewController as! PredictorTableViewController
        self.grandPrix.append(GrandPrix(granPrix: TrackTextField.text!, firstDriver: firstTextField.text!, secondDriver: secondTextField.text!, thirdDriver: thirdTextField.text!))
        vc.grandPrix = self.grandPrix


    }
}
```

I have used TrackTextField to test out if the alert works. As it happens when I click on Grandprix Predictor the UIAlert does not appear. Below is the function that segue's to the next UIViewController.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "getPredictor" {
        let predictorVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let vc = predictorVC.topViewController as! PredictorTableViewController
        self.grandPrix.append(GrandPrix(granPrix: TrackTextField.text!, firstDriver: firstTextField.text!, secondDriver: secondTextField.text!, thirdDriver: thirdTextField.text!))
        vc.grandPrix = self.grandPrix


    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check should not be done in the picker view delegate.

The answer really depends on what even you want to use to trigger the check. Most likely you want to do the check when some button is clicked after the user should have filled in all four text fields.

Add a `verifyInput` method. Something like:

```
func verifyInput() -> Bool {
    if TrackTextField.text?.isEmpty || firstTextField.text?.isEmpty || secondTextField.text?.isEmpty || thirdTextField.text?.isEmpty {
        // at least one is empty, show your alert here
        return false
    } else {
        return true // all good
    }
}
```

Then call `verifyInput` from some button handler or perhaps `shouldPerformSegue`. Again, it depends on what event you want to use to trigger the check.

Example:

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    // Only validate for this specific segue
    if identifier == "getPredictor" {
        return verifyInput()
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Adjust the logic as needed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the validateInput bit.  Not sure how I would use the verifyInput function in the prepare(for segue : UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) ?

Comment: You don't use it in `prepare`. That's too late. That's why I showed you clear example of using `shouldPerformSegue`.