# iOS Swift4 how to check if string is not nil and not empty?

Tags: ios, string, swift4

**How do I check if an optional string object is neither empty string "" nor nil in Swift4?** I end up having to write weird checks like these, because

```
 //object has instance variable     
 var title: String?

 //invalid comparison - cannot compare optional and non optional
 if object.title?.count > 0
 {

 }

 //valid but ugly
 if object.titleString == nil {
      //has nil title
 }
 if let title = object.title
 {
    if title.count == 0
    {
        //has a "" string
    }
 }
```

Comment: see this may be it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381994/check-string-for-nil-empty

Comment: if !(title?.isEmpty ?? true)  { /* do you stuff */ }

Comment: there's something to be said for spelling it out in full: `if title != nil && !title!.isEmpty`

Answer (score 12):

I would go with something like

```
if let title = object.title, !title.isEmpty {
  // it's not nil nor an empty string
}
```