# Check if string is not nil or not empty using Swift 5

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I want to utilize something that has the best performance, but also check for both `nil` and also `not empty` on strings.

**Example**: If the string is not nil, but also not empty, show `showLinkButton`.

So I was able to use this code:

```
if let website = item.website, !item.website.isEmpty {
    showLinkButton
}
```

Where I have a `@ViewBuilder` such as this:

```
@ViewBuilder private var showLinkButton: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.isBrowsingWebsite = true
    }, label: {
        Image(systemName: "link")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(height: 14)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .padding(5)
    })
    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color(.systemGray6))
    )
    .sheet(isPresented: $isBrowsingWebsite) {
        SafariViewWrapper(url: URL(string: item.website)!)
    }
}
```

**Problem**:
The problem is that I'm not really doing anything with `let website`, so I am getting the following errors:

`Immutable value 'website' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it` && `Replace 'let website' with '_'`.

**Questions**:

- If I utilize `if _ = item.website, !item.website.isEmpty`, will this hurt performance? Is there a better way to do it?
- Since I will have multiple if statements, would `if _ = ...` have negative side effects being called 5+ times in the same View.

Comment: `if let website = item.website, !item.website.isEmpty {` should be `if let website = item.website, !website.isEmpty {`. Then you won't get the warning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check string for nil & empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381994/check-string-for-nil-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *optional chaining* to call `isEmpty` and compare explicitly to `false`:

```
if item.website?.isEmpty == false {
    print("not nil and not empty")
}
```

Note:

If you want to check if a value is `nil`, just compare it to `nil`.  Don't use `if let` unless you want to use the unwrapped value.

Comment: I am getting this error `Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'String'`. Could I utilize it without the optional `?` - Nvm, I updated the `var website: String?`.

Comment: @theMap If `website` isn't optional then your whole question becomes irrelevant.

Comment: A value can't be `nil` unless it is an *optional*.  Why are you trying to test if it is `nil` if it isn't *optional*?

Comment: If the value coming from the database can be `nil`, then the variable you are storing it in should be an *optional*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @vacawama, I will update the variable to handle optional.